# onDoubleClick asp image not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, image

I am working on a project and I need to be able to call a java script function when double clicking on a image. So far, for testing, I was using the On Click function and it was working perfectly, but now that I added the "Double" work it doesn't seem to work.

Please see below the code on the asp image:

```
<asp:Image href="#" ID="MapImage" runat="server" Height="601px" Width="469px" OnDoubleClick="javascript:MapImage_Click()"/>
```

This is the java script function code:

```
function MapImage_Click() {
 alert('hello');
}
```

Do anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ondblclick="MapImage_Click();"

Answer (score 2):

Use `ondblclick` instead of `OnDoubleClick`.

Correct code would be `<asp:Image href="#" ID="MapImage" runat="server" Height="601px" Width="469px" ondblclick="javascript:MapImage_Click()"/>`